# Using ternary operations to make my code cleaner

Tags: c#, conditional-operator

I have been doing some C# practice problems for a while and I want to start playing with ternary operations to make my code cleaner.

Here is my code:

```
public static string Bomb(string txt)
        {
            txt.ToLower().Contains("bomb") == true ? "Duck!!!" : "There is no bomb, relax.";
        }
```

So basically if Bomb("xxxxxx") contains the string "bomb" it will return "Duck!!!" if not it will return "There is no bomb, relax."

But for some reason, this doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `return`

```
public static string Bomb(string txt)
{
    return txt.ToLower().Contains("bomb") == true ? "Duck!!!" : "There is no bomb, relax.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ternary operator looks OK, but you're missing a `return` statement from the function. Also note that `Contains` returns a boolean, so the `== true` is redundant:

So I have been doing some c# practice problems for a while and I want to start playing with ternary operations to make my code cleaner.

Here is my code:

```
public static string Bomb(string txt)
{
    return txt.ToLower().Contains("bomb") ? "Duck!!!" : "There is no bomb, relax.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you missed the return part in the function

```
public static string Bomb(string txt)
        {
            return txt.ToLower().Contains("bomb") ? "Duck!!!" : "There is no bomb, relax.";
        }
```